# Form validation using javascipt or hibernate

Tags: javascript, validation, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

Hi I wanted to know that we can use hibernate validator with spring jdbctemplate or it can be used only while using hibernate frameowrk?

And also which is a better approach to validate the form -- Hibernate validator or using javascript?

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Please refer, [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use java persistence api for validation if you want, however, using javascript would be a better option since it can be easily integrated into your forms and can detect changes in form faster using events such as `onkeyup()` for example.